# Why isn't the string var bound to my text area being updated when i'm typing?

Tags: angular

I have a small piece of code that looks like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
  <label for="comment">Motivatie:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" [(value)]= "motivation"></textarea>
  <br><br>
</div>
```

Its supposed to update the motivation variable when i'm typing but nothing happens. When I use [(ngModel)] instead I get an error so I would rather use value. `motivation` is declared as a string in the component.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what kind of error is thrown when you're using ngModel instead?

Comment: you should be able to use ngModel

Comment: in order to use ngModel you must import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms'; in your module and import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms'; in your app.module

Comment: I want to say you must import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms'; in your component